# Problems using protractor to find elements on angular site with ag-grid

Tags: angular, protractor, ag-grid

I am writing tests for an angular (7.3.1) site that uses ag-grid 20.1.0 with a fairly large scrollable grid that refreshes periodically.

The code will not find any element on any pages that have the grid unless I do 
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

Otherwise, it always fails with:

Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 34 seconds

It almost feels like angular thinks that the page never completes loading. Perhaps because it is set to auto-refresh?

Because the grid is on 99% of the pages, I have to do it pretty much everywhere.
This results in the fact that I am unable to utilize angular and have to rely on browser.wait and browser.sleep

Am I do ing something wrong? Is there any way to make it work without disabling waitForAngularEnabled?

Comment: A vague description of the problem you have is unlikely to yield any usable answer- could you please supply code and the exact error message in a minimal to reproduce fashion?

Comment: Ag-grid only renders limited rows and columns for the performance issue. Make sure your test is not looking for not loaded elements. For example rows that have not rendered yet.

Comment: If your site is Angular 2+ can you open up chrome dev tools and run the command `getAllAngularTestabilities()`. Within the object returned there will be two properties within _ngZone called hasPendingMacrotasks and hasPendingMicrotasks. These are the properties Protractor will wait to be `false` before proceeding with the tests (I believe). Do you ever see both these value being `false`?

Answer (score 0):

To handle wait issues:

use `browser.waitforAngularEnabled(false)` after getting your base url. Then you can use expected waits which makes the protractor wait until that expectation is completed.

Refer https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions for more details

Hope it helps you

Comment: The poster specifically mentioned they are looking for alternatives for using `waitForAngularEnabled`

Comment: Ya..but poster application has a auto refresh call enabled which make the waitForAngular(true) to be incomplete and leads to test fails.The solution given will help the user to run the test without `browser.sleep()`.

Comment: Cool, in that case I would probably suggest explaining why this approach may be suitable given the context of the users question in your answer.

Comment: Yes, I do use browser.waitforAngularEnabled(false) across all the code. And, yes, I was looking for an alternative solution. I wasn't sure if the refresh is the root cause of the issue. As far as I can see page loads fully, but protractor just sits and waits for something unless waitforAngular is disabled. I was hoping that there is some way to tell protractor to ignore refresh

Comment: U can confirm that the page is complete by give `F12` and navigate to network tab.
Now `refresh` your page.Now all your http request will be processed  in network tab.U would see a continuous call going.So that is the reason for protractor wait.